# A monotonicity-type property for probabilities

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a continuous random variable (with distribution $f$, say). Let $g\colon\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be strictly increasing, differentiable why not. Then is it true that $$\mathbb P(X\leq x)=\mathbb P(g(X)\leq g(x))?$$ My intuition and drawing of pictures says yes, but my "first-principle" approaches have failed me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is not for a class but for my own curiosity, so any approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very "first principles" approach. I hope it's not too pedantic.

From the fact that $g$ is increasing, we know that $X \leq x$ implies $g(X) \leq g(x)$, hence $\{ X \leq x \} \subseteq \{ g(X) \leq g(x) \}$ and $P(X \leq x) \leq P(g(X) \leq g(x))$.

From the fact that $g$ is *strictly* increasing, we know that $X > x$ implies $g(X) > g(x)$, hence $\{ X > x \} \subseteq \{ g(X) > g(x) \}$. Taking complements, we find that $\{ X \leq x \} \supseteq \{g(X) \leq g(x) \}$, which implies $P(X \leq x) \geq P(g(X) \leq g(x))$.

The result follows from the final inequalities in last two paragraphs.

Comment: Not pedantic, I was figuring it was a simple observation like this but apparently my brain has shut down for the evening.

Answer (score 1):

Since $g$ is increasing, $y\leq x$ implies $g(y)\leq g(x)$.  Since $g$ is strictly increasing, $y>x$ implies $g(y)>g(x)$.  Thus $g(y)\leq g(x)$ iff $y\leq x$.  So $\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}=\{\omega:g(X(\omega))\leq g(x)\}$, and so these sets have the same measure.

Comment: I appreciate the concise response. I was messing around with a change of variables in the integral definition but I don't think I was doing it correctly